# Application Insights custom telemetry in Azure Bot Service

Tags: botframework, azure-application-insights, azure-functions, botconnector, azure-bot-service

I have managed to add the AI dependencies and able to import/using in .csx files, but I'm not seeing any telemetry on the Application Insights resource.

All usage, Browser, Servers charts are empty except Failed requests and one custom event 'Activity'.

In my `project.json` I mentioned all AI dependencies like below:

```
{  "frameworks": {
"net46":{
  "dependencies": {
  "Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure": "3.1",
   "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights": "2.1.0",
  "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Agent.Intercept": "1.2.1",
  "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Azure.WebSites": "2.1.3",
  "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector": "2.1.0",
  "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PerfCounterCollector": "2.1.0",
  "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TraceListener": "2.1.0",
  "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web": "2.1.0",
  "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer": "2.1.0",
  "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel": "2.1.0",
  "Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure": "1.0.0.0"
  }
}
}
}
```

Then I tried to use a method like below in the `Dialog` class under `MessageReceivedAsync`:

```
await context.PostAsync($"{this.count++}: You said {message.Text}");
        TelemetryClient telemetry = new TelemetryClient();
        telemetry.TrackEvent("MessageReceivedAsync");
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
```

Can anyone help with implementing it?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a reference to a working sample using Application Insights.

https://github.com/christopheranderson/azure-functions-app-insights-sample/tree/master/cs-http

I hope this helps!